# How to handle make-process output including control character

Tags: shell, emacs, control-characters

I want to handle `make-process` output including control character.

```
(setq proc
      (make-process
       :name "sh"
       :buffer (get-buffer-create "*proc*")
       :command '("hub" "clone" "emacs-mirror/emacs")
       :filter (lambda (proc string)
                 (when (buffer-live-p (process-buffer proc))
                   (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
                     (let ((moving (= (point) (process-mark proc))))
                       (save-excursion
                         (goto-char (process-mark proc))
                         (insert string)
                         (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point)))
                       (if moving (goto-char (process-mark proc)))))))))
```

But, control character inserted as-is. How to handle it like shell?

[image]

Note: Maybe related manual page

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-from-Processes.html#Output-from-Processes

Comment: When terminal sees the control character \r, it moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, you can replace \r with \n, it should give better output, though not perfect.

Comment: Yes, replace \r with \n generate a better result, but Elisp shell simulator(M-x eshell, shell) works well. I think Emacs should have this handle function or method...?

Comment: It seems Eshell simply deletes the whole current line when it sees \r according to eshell-handle-control-codes

Comment: Thanks, your pointer. Eshell is good teacher for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eshell internal output filter generates a good result.

Needless whole Eshell (don't enter `eshell-mode`), setting some markers makes us able to use `eshell-output-filter` function.

```lisp
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*proc*")
  (set (make-local-variable 'eshell-last-input-start) (point-marker))
  (set (make-local-variable 'eshell-last-input-end) (point-marker))
  (set (make-local-variable 'eshell-last-output-start) (point-marker))
  (set (make-local-variable 'eshell-last-output-end) (point-marker))
  (set (make-local-variable 'eshell-last-output-block-begin) (point)))
;;=> 1

(setq proc
      (make-process
       :name "sh"
       :buffer (get-buffer-create "*proc*")
       :command '("hub" "clone" "emacs-mirror/emacs")
       :filter (lambda (proc string)
                 (when (buffer-live-p (process-buffer proc))
                   (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
                     (let ((moving (= (point) (process-mark proc))))
                       (save-excursion
                         (goto-char (process-mark proc))
                         (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
                           (eshell-output-filter proc string))
                         (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point)))
                       (if moving (goto-char (process-mark proc)))))))))
;;=> #<process sh>

(delete-process proc)    ; kill the process when you want
;;=> nil
```